# How to limit text length where the text changes dynamically?

Tags: flutter

I have two dropdown menus, what you select in the first one determines what options are listed in the second one. I'm trying to limit the length of the text options in the second one, since when you select one it can be too long and cause an overflow error. The way I am attempting to limit the length of the text only party works currently. If the text is longer than the limit I have set, it will shorten it like how I want. But if the text is shorter than the limit I have set, it will error out saying `RangeError: Value not in range: 25`. How would I go about limiting text size better to avoid this issue?

This is where I currently try to limit text size.

```
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value.length > 10 ? '${value.substring(0, 25)}...' : value)
                      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text widget have a property 'overflow', which you can set like

```
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
```

It will put '...' at the end of the string, if it does not fit the width provided