# Is there a way to calculate text width before it render?

Tags: flutter

I have a fixed-size box that I need to pass the height value.

Inside the box, I have a Text widget that could overflow so I need to set the 'maxLines' 2. However, because the box height is fixed, the Text widget will not take 2 lines.

I can pass a larger value to the height of the box, but it doesn't look nice if the Text widget only takes up 1 line.

It would be nice if I can calculate the total pixel of the Text widget then work out how many lines the Text widget is needed by comparing it with the width of the fixed-size box.

```dart
    SizedBox(
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
        maxLines: 2,
      ),
      width: 300,
      height: 60,
    ),
```

for example

```dart
      height: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.fontSize * title.length > 300? 72 : 60
```

Comment: ```Expanded``` seems like the solution you are looking for

Comment: Why do you need to fix the height? You can use Container(width: 300) without specifying the height. Then, it will adjust the height of the container according to its content. If it is one line, it will shrink , if it is two line, it will become larger. Use padding if you want to make it look better.

Comment: you can use render  object to get the size of the text height and width both but for that, you need to add that call in post-frame call back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit text length where the text changes dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64598513/how-to-limit-text-length-where-the-text-changes-dynamically)

Comment: @ArpitAwasthi Thank you for your comment. I need to display all text.

Comment: @FarhanSyah SizedBox is an example, the actual widget I'm using is `SliverPersistentHeader` which I need to provide fixed height.

Comment: @UTKARSHSharma Yes I noticed that but that seems to overkill what I want to achieve. my current solution is `height: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.fontSize * posting.detail.title.length > 500 ? 72 : 58` where I can use `MediaQuery' to calculate exact value I decided to give it aproximate value of 500.

Comment: @e-j5 though you can specify the width and height of a text using the fitted box and set property like fit: BoxFit.fill   still its not a good solution.

Answer (score 9):

here is the answer

```
  Size calcTextSize(String text, TextStyle style) {
    final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      textScaleFactor: WidgetsBinding.instance.window.textScaleFactor,
    )..layout();
    return textPainter.size;
  }

final double textWidth = calcTextSize(text, TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize)).width;
```

Comment: if you have a problem with `TextDirection.ltr` use `import 'dart:ui' as ui;` and then `ui.TextDirection.ltr`